# Adding And Removing Fields To CiviCRM Tables

Tags: civievent, database

I had earlier added a new field to the civicrm_event table called "enable_tracking".
I achieved this by adding a new field to the xml/schema/Event/Event.xml file.
After this I ran the regen.sh script. Everything worked fine.

Now I wanted to remove this field from the civicrm_event table, so I removed the field from the Event.xml file and ran regen.sh again. However I am getting an error when running this script.

```
+ echo 'Populating database with dataset - civicrm_generated.mysql'
Populating database with dataset - civicrm_generated.mysql
+ mysql -udrupalclea_vpj3r -XXXXXXXXXXXXX -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 drupalclea_vpj3r
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 462: Unknown column 'enable_tracking' in 'field list'
```

One hack would be to manually edit the civicrm_generated.mysql file. Is there any other way?

Comment: To clarify, you are working on a patch for CiviCRM core, and not an extension or customization?

Comment: Because if you are working on an extension or customization, adding columns to a civicm core table is not recommended practice :-)

Comment: @Coleman I am working on an extension. Since it is in an initial phase I am currently making changes directly to core, later I will write code for it as an extension.

Comment: @ErikH I was just experimenting, I have removed the column which I had added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the civi process works great for adding columns. Dropping columns is not done too often and hence the above error.

I suspect the easiest work-around might be to empty out the civicrm_generated file:

```
echo '' > civicrm_generated.mysql
```

and then run regen.sh (this basically makes setup.sh load an empty file, and hence avoid the error). Maybe this should be part of the regen.sh script